# Symfony DateTime before 1902

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I currently code a symfony project that requires saving many dates below 1091. In MySQL, DateTime recording is good. But when I refreshed the page, the value displayed is wrong. I use a datetime field including the following code:

```
$builder->add(
    'datetimepublish',
    DateTimeType::class,
    [
        'model_timezone' => date_default_timezone_get(),
        'view_timezone' => date_default_timezone_get(),
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
        'label' => 'Date et heure',
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Date et heure',
        ],
    ]
);
```

This behavior would be a 'normal', I searched a bit in the vendor, and I think I find when it did that, the DataTransformer. How to cure it?

Comment: [`DateTimeType`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/ae0a20519e65f9e4bfdcb8cd957932f1b6462936/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php#L66) either produces a valid [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) PHP object or throws an exception. The `DateTime` class uses 64-bit integers to store the value internally, its range is much larger than 1902-2038 (the range of 32-bit Unix timestamps). `DateTime` can store dates for [292 billion years in the past and the same in the future](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php). Most probably the error is in your code.

Comment: When you have datetime like today, `2016-05-11 10:10`, it works or give you an error?

Comment: All dates between 1902 and 2038 registers well and appears well on my form. The dates that are not in this interval registers well in MySQL I have 1800-02-29 12:03, but in the form the date displayed will be completely different. If I display the date with Twig `{{ entity.datepublish|date("d/m/Y H:i") }}` it gives 29/02/1800 12:03. But in the input field of the form there is a completely different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue here and discovered that it's most likely you work on a 32-bit system and symfony somewhere uses a timestamp representation of the date, which php on 32-bit systems can't handle if the year is one before 1902.
It's amazing.
@see:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5227

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I have taken the solution to change the vendor, even if it is not recommended.
But it works and it will allow me to move forward.